# Try/Exception trigger for Angle calculation in Python

Tags: python, try-except

I have a code snippet from another project, and haven't been able to get in touch with the original author to verify some behavior. Within his program, there are a series of try/except statements with respect to angle calculation, and I'm having a hard time getting what condition would trigger an exception (if any). This particular calculation is looped through many times, so if I can avoid testing conditions, I'd like to.

```
import math

try:
    vec_rox = [math.tan(rox/2.0), 0.0, 0.0]
except:
    vec_rox = [math.tan(math.pi/2.0), 0.0, 0.0]
```

rox is expected to be a smallish scalar. I'm guessing the except is meant to work if a value error is triggered by the tan evaluation, but I can't find a value that would do so.

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a typo, fixed.

Comment: May be for infinite value of tan like tan90 since a variable cannot handle infinite

Comment: @PavanKumarTS: That can't happen, though, since the argument to `tan` is in radians, so the inputs for which `tan` is infinite are the odd integer multiples of `pi/2`, and none of those multiples is exactly representable in binary floating-point. Neither can overflow happen in a correctly-rounded `tan` implementation, but showing that is a bit more involved.